# Kvm disk increase

Tags: linux, kvm, lvm

How can I increase the size of a disk allocated to a KVM machine ?
It can be lvm, raw file etc.

thanks

Comment: This question belongs on serverfault.com, not SO. SO is for programming related questions (i.e. code).

Answer (score 1):

and if it isn't lvm, you can use qemu-img to resize the disk, after that you need to start os (or usb qemu-nbd) to start the virtual machine, grow the partition and filesystem too.

Answer (score 0):

If it's LVM, then you simply use lvresize to resize the disk.

Something like this:

lzresize -L +5G /dev/pv_name/vol_name

And then, once done, run:

resize2fs /dev/pv_name/vol_name

Just substitute "pv_name" & "vol_name" with your actual LVM names